# What to look (out) for when buying a (second-hand) electronic drum kit?

Tags: drum-kits, electronic-drumset

I'm a beginner drummer (only had 4 lessons so far) and I am thinking about buying an electronic drum kit. I've read [this post](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/3514/1881) and [this post](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/15598/1881) on buying a beginner drum kit, but both seem to be almost entirely about buying an acoustic kit.

- What are the differences when buying a beginner electronic drum kit (as opposed to acoustic)?

I'd like the kit to last for a while, so

- How long will a beginner kit suffice, or do you outgrow it quickly? Is there a big difference between beginner, intermediate or pro electronic kits when it comes to sound quality?

Finally, one of my options is to buy a second-hand kit, so:

- What are the things I should be looking for or avoid when checking out a second-hand electronic kit?

I hope these aren't too many questions. I'm willing to spread them over multiple questions if that's better.

I'm not sure if it matters, but my budget is somewhere around 500-900 euro's (that's $660-$1200) and I'm hoping I can use the drum kit for both practicing and playing a few easy songs in my hobby band (perhaps even at a gig).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Really Depends on the quality of the electronic drum kit your are buying, the thing you should look out for the most is how responsive the heads and cymbals are. I've plaid some shoddy electric kits in my time where it is delayed from the time you hit the pad to the sound playing it is very minute, the timing delay but for a drummer, the timing needs to be perfect or you risk going out of time with the song and so forth when in practice. Also there are naturally things an acoustic kit can do that an electric kit cant, like choking cymbals and performing rim hits.

The most obvious of differences between Acoustic and electric is the time in which it takes to set up as well as the space in which it takes up. also you wont annoy your neighbours quite as much with electric. But you get a much more authentic and better quality sound from acoustic. the maintenance of an acoustic set requires ALOT more attention. But the cost of electricity is increased with electric. Overall Acoustic is a lot more expensive. the sticks wont degrade half as quickly with electric sets and the heads arguably last longer than the skins for acoustic heads.

If you are buying second hand check the quality of the wires as they can stop the drums working completely. each head has a separate wire. Also pay very close attention to the sensitivity of the foot pedals I once tested a kit that doubled and even tripled up strokes on the hi hit foot pedal so when I pressed the pedal once it hit twice and three times and wouldn't clamp down as a closed hi hat. the springs also in the foot pedals need to be checked for rust and so on. **Do not be fobbed off with faulty equipment, test it fully before buying it.** things are easily covered up with electric drum kits in my opinion.

I am editing as things spring to my mind here  but also do not leave either kit (Acoustic or Electric) in damp areas, it can take no time at all in killing either. the wires and electronics are a lot more susceptible to damage than on a good hardy shell of an acoustic with its metal stands and clamps but springs in the adjusters of the acoustic kit can also rust making it a pain to adjust them. plastic makes the electric kit easier to adjust and set up.